# How can I parse the leaderboard data returned from Google's API?

Tags: unity, android, google-play

We're developing our first Android game and we want to get leaderboard data from [Google Play Game Services](https://developers.google.com/games/services/web/api/index) and use the score data from the different leaderboards.

I am able to use Unity's `WWW` class to get the plain text results of (for example) [this data](https://www.googleapis.com/games/v1/players/playerId/leaderboards/leaderboardId/scores/timeSpan), but handling would take a lot of parsing, wouldn't it?

Comment: The data returned from that URL is json. Can't you use Unity's SimpleJSON module to process it?

Comment: I can see this was answered correctly, but I new see that the question was all wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google's APIs return JSON data. The format of that is described by the API documentation (for example, the format of the leaderboard data is [here](https://developers.google.com/games/services/web/api/leaderboards)).

You are correct that parsing it yourself would be involved. However, the good news is that there are already several APIs that will parse JSON into more-friendly data structures your code can consume. [SimpleJSON](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/SimpleJSON), as mentioned in the comments, is one such option.

Once you have such an API up and running, you can feed the plain-text response you got from the `WWW` module into it. Most APIs have a method to do so; for example, with SimpleJSON you'd do something like:

```
using SimpleJSON;

// ...elsewhere in some handler code...
var root = JSON.Parse(wwwResponseText);
```

Then you can access the children of the `root` object like you'd access a dictionary (and you can treat JSON arrays as C# arrays). For example, if `wwwResponseText` contained a leaderboard result like:

```
{
  "kind": "games#leaderboard",
  "id": string,
  "name": string,
  "iconUrl": string,
  "isIconUrlDefault": boolean,
  "order": string
}
```

you could recover the ID and name of that leaderboard like:

```
var leaderboardId = root["id"].ToString();
var leaderboardName = root["name"].ToString();
```